# How can I prevent my iPod from downloading album art?

Tags: ipod, itunes

I have a first-gen iPod Nano 4GB. I live having album art in my iTunes library on my nice, big, fat, PC hard drive. However, I don't really need it on my iPod. I'd like to maximize the amount of music I can fit on there.

So, how much space is that album art taking up, anyway? Can I keep it from getting on the device without having to delete it all from iTunes?

Answer (score 4):

There used to be an option in iTunes 8 that allowed toggling of album artwork on devices.  **This was removed in iTunes 9.**

I also have your model Nano and would like to disable the artwork - only recourse for us is to [leave feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/itunesapp.html) :(

Comment: I **knew** I'd seen that setting before. Urgh. Here's hoping it comes back. (I left feedback as well, but my hopes aren't high.)